# Gradle issue in elasticsearch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch, gradle

Gradle 2.13 is required to assemble ElasticSearch. But sudo apt-get install gradle installs 2.14 version which is giving build failure. How can i install gradle 2.13 version ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I removed the gradle 2.14 version by

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gradle
```

Then download gradle 2.13 version by:

```
mkdir -p ~/opt/packages/gradle && cd $_

wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip

unzip gradle-2.3-bin.zip
```

Next Install and setup gradle by :

```
ln -s ~/opt/packages/gradle/gradle-2.3/ ~/opt/gradle
```

Open your .profile file in vi, emacs, or gedit.

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Paste the following at the bottom of your .profile file.

```
# Gradle
if [ -d "$HOME/opt/gradle" ]; then
    export GRADLE_HOME="$HOME/opt/gradle"
    PATH="$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
fi
```

Finally, source your .profile and test gradle.

```
source ~/.profile

which gradle

gradle -version
```

And it worked fine for me.

Comment: Hopefully this is only a temporary requirement. But here's why incase you were curious why it required `2.13` explicitly: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/9bbf3fc1d93d70facc9cee08b3f9de1dba7a18b0

Comment: why do you install gradle-2.3 if it requires 2.13 ?